# Checking for odd digits in a number

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that checks if all digits in a number are odd, but the cout which says that the number is made only out of odd digits shows only if the inputed number is 1 digit long.
Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int n, c;
    cin >> n;
    while (n != 0) {
        c = n % 10;
        if (c % 2 == 1) {
            n = n / 10;
            if (n == 0) {
                cout << " Number has only odd digits";
            }
        }
        else
            cout << " Number doesn't have only odd digits";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please sort out the indentation

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code line by line and the problem should become very obvious.

Comment: what a mess....

Comment: Problem is obvious, as suggested use a debugger and step through the program to debug.

Comment: The decision whether or not the number has only odd digits should be made **OUTSIDE** the loop. Fix your algorithm accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend keeping the number as a string, then searching the string for odd digits:

```
static const char odd_digits[] = "13579";
std::string number_as_text;
std::cin >> number_as_text;
std::string::size_type  position;
position = number_as_text.find_first_of(odd_digits);
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
  std::cout << "Number has at least one odd digit.\n";
}
```

The number, as a string, is searched for any character from a list of odd digits.

Answer (score 0):

I made minimal changes so as to preserve your original flow of thought. The `n=n/10` need to be executed in `else` cases. Added handling of the case of `input as 0`. Added a `return(0)` statement when you detect a even digit (there is no point in continuing, so returned from there).

```
int main() {    
    int n, c;
    cin >> n;

    if (n==0) {
        cout << "Number is zero. So it doesn't have only odd digits" << endl;
        return(0);
    }

    while (n != 0) {
        c = n % 10; n = n / 10;    
        cout << "n=" << n << " c=" << c << endl;

        if (c % 2 == 1) {
            if (n == 0) {
                cout << "Number has only odd digits" << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Number doesn't have only odd digits" << endl;
            return(0);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is these lines:

```
else
    cout << " Number doesn't have only odd digits";
    return 0;
```

The compiler is interpreting this as:

```
else {
    cout << " Number doesn't have only odd digits";
}
return 0;
```

Which means it is always executing the `return` regardless of whether `c` is odd or even.  To fix this, add explicit braces to your else clause:

```
else {
    cout << " Number doesn't have only odd digits";
    return 0;
}
```

This kind of error is why most style guides require you to always use braces after `if` and `else`, even if there is only one line.

Comment: Also knows as a [`goto fail;`](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) bug.